# IBM MobileFirst 7 - Bulk Send Message error indications are incomplete

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am sending an array of push messages to the bulk send message API in IBM MobileFirst 7. Each of the messages sends successfully individually, when sending through the basic send message API, and I can combine the messages into an array and send successfully through the bulk send message API.

However, if I deliberately make one message target a non-existent device ID, ALL of the messages will fail to send, and the error array does not indicate which message was the failure.

Is there a way to get more information about which message failed?  Is there a way to have the bulk send message API not fail entirely when just one message results in failure?  I don't see anything in [the docs found here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_send_bulk_messages_post.html) about either of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a valid defect. If you are IBM customer or Business Partner , can you please open a PMR. You can quote this discussion in the PMR.